# Returning Generics from functions without parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I'm just getting into the more sophisticated typehinting stuff in Python, in particular, `typing.Generic`.

Say I have a base class and a subclass of that:

```py
class Base:
    def base_method(self):
        pass


class Sub(Base):
    def sub_method(self):
        pass
```

Now I want to create a class that will have an instance variable that can be "a `Base` or any subclass thereof". To do this, I must make use of `typing.TypeVar` and `typing.Generic`:

```py
class FullyTypedContainer(Generic[BaseOrSubclass]):
    def __init__(self, p: BaseOrSubclass):
        self._p = p

    @property
    def p(self) -> BaseOrSubclass:
        return self._p
```

This works great; the type of `p` is "passed along" via `BaseOrSubclass` so that language servers like PyLance will see that `FullTypedContainer(Sub()).p` has a method called `sub_method()` but `FullyTypedContainer(Base()).p` does not.

So what's the typehint for this function?

```py
def get_random_list_of_containers():
    a = random.randint(0, 1)
    if a == 0:
        return [FullyTypedContainer(Sub()), FullyTypedContainer(Base())]
    else:
        return [FullyTypedContainer(Base()), FullyTypedContainer(Sub())]
```

- `-> typing.List[FullyTypedContainer]`: doesn't specify the type of `FullyTypedContainer` and so it seems that `get_list_of_containers()[0].p` is seen as type `Any`.
- `-> typing.List[FullyTypedContainer[Base]]`: "coerces" everything to be of type `Base`, (not `Base` or one of its subclasses) and so `get_list_of_containers()[0].p` is seen as never having the method `sub_method()`.
- `-> typing.List[FullyTypedContainer[typing.Union[Base, Sub]]`: seems to be the best option, but would require me to manually maintain a list of every subclass of `Base`.

Comment: Do you actually need lists? Should this maybe be a `tuple`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `tuple` or `list` is irrelevant; the point is that I want to know how to typehint `Generics` returned from a function without parameters.

Comment: Well, it is relevant because tuples can contain and can be typed heterogeneously, but lists must be homogenous

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see that now, but it's actually counter to my question, so I'm editing.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what exactly your expectation is. Since the output is entirely random, a type checker must *always* assume the worst case of ``Base``. Even if it is "``Base`` or a subclass", that still means no more capabilities than ``Base`` are guaranteed. There is no way for a type checker to know that ``get_list_of_containers()[0].p`` is definitely not just a ``Base``. So, can you clarify what the type checker should infer from the annotation in practice?

Answer (score 0):

lists are homogenous in their type: all elements have the same static type. The best you can do is `List[FullyTypedContainer[Base]]` or `List[FullyTypedContainer[Union[Base, Sub]]`. Or use a custom collection that allows you to constrain particular contents to particular types and use that instead of list

Comment: Edited my question to get away from this `tuple` suggestion; in the actual case I'm facing, the list contents are not known at script time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here, and both issues are related to [variance of generic types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types): both `List` and your custom generic type `FullyTypedContainer` are invariant.

Assume `Sub` is a subtype of `Base`. Given a generic type `GenType`:

- If `GenType[Sub]` is a subtype of `GenType[Base]`, then it is **covariant**. A lot of containers are intuitively covariant.
- If `GenType[Base]` is a subtype of `GenType[Sub]`, then it is **contravariant**. This sounds counterintuitive, but the `Callable` type is actually contravariant w.r.t its argument types. A callable that takes a `Base` argument can be used where we require a callable that takes a `Sub` argument.
- If neither of the above holds, then `GenType` is **invariant**.

The Python `List` type is invariant, and the variance of `Generic` types depends on its `TypeVar` -- and `TypeVar`s by default are invariant. So to correctly type annotate your function, you need to make two changes:

- Use a covariant sequence type, e.g. `Sequence`.
- Make the `BaseOrSubclass` type variable covariant as well.

In code, it would look like this:

```
BaseOrSubclass = TypeVar("BaseOrSubclass", bound=Base, covariant=True)

class FullyTypedContainer(Generic[BaseOrSubclass]):
    def __init__(self, p: BaseOrSubclass): ...

def get_list_of_containers() -> Sequence[FullyTypedContainer[Base]]:
    return [FullyTypedContainer(Sub()), FullyTypedContainer(Base())]
```

Here's a more complete example on mypy-play: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=85af8d25521c9d4b8454719685b37fc8

---

*A note on `List` vs. `Sequence`:*

Technically `List` is not equivalent to `Sequence`:

- `List` always refers to the type for the builtin `list`.
- `Sequence` is any "list-like" type that defines `__getitem__`, `__len__`, a few other methods like `__reverse__` and `count` etc. This also covers the `tuple`, `str`, `bytes` types and such.

Comment: `List` is a `MutableSequence`

Comment: I don't think this is related to covariance, or that adding covariance solves the problem. Even with a `Sequence[FullyTypedContainer[Base]]` and covariance you still lose the static types of each element (beyond being `Base`s)

Comment: @joel But as you said, lists / sequences are homogeneous, and there's just no way to encode the types of each individual element. `Sequence[T]` means that each element is either of type `T`, or of some subtype of `T`, which I think is what OP wants. If OP wants to encode "only `Base` and its subtype `Sub`, and none of the other subtypes", then I agree that `List[FullyTypedContainer[Union[Base, Sub]]]` is the more accurate type, but then you still need to make `FullyTypedContainer` covariant (or use `List[Union[FullyTypedContainer[Base], FullyTypedContainer[Sub]]]`).

Comment: @ZecongHu good point about `List[FullyTypedContainer[Union[Base, Sub]]`. I think `List[FullyTypedContainer[Base]]` is better anyway. Perhaps the problem is that it's not exactly clear what OP wants the function to do. I'm basing my answer on the fact they're testing with `get_list_of_containers()[0].p`. Once you index, covariance is irrelevant

Comment: sorry, once you `[0].p`, covariance is irrelevant